# NReco PdfGenerator character or letter spacing

Tags: css, pdf, pdf-generation, letter-spacing

I am using Nreco PdfGenerator to generate pdf from HTML. Everything is fine but characters are so close to each other and it is not easy to read.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

HTML version
[image]

PDF version
[image]

This is my CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background: #fff; text-rendering: optimizeSpeed; }
    .topButton { width: 880px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; background: #fff; border-bottom: 2px solid #007182; }
    .mainTable { width: 880px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; background: #fff; /*border: 1px solid red;*/ }
    .just { text-align: justify; }
    .detailItinerary { width: 100%; border: 10px solid red; }
    .dailyTitle { color: #4C9897; margin-top: 10px; display: block; font-size: 12px; }
    .serviceRowsWithBorder { width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #007182; padding: 10px 0; }
    .serviceRowsWithoutBorder { width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; }
    .topLink { text-decoration: none; color: #C74E1B; }
</style>
<style media="print">
    .topButton { display: none; }
    @page { size: auto; margin: 7mm; }
    body { background: #fff; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-rendering: optimizeSpeed; }
    .mainTable { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; background: #fff; /*border: 1px solid red;*/ }
    .just { text-align: justify; }
    .dailyTitle { color: #4C9897; margin-top: 10px; display: block; font-size: 12px; }
    .serviceRowsWithBorder { width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #007182; padding: 10px 0; }
    .serviceRowsWithoutBorder { width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: [Essential PDF](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/htmltopdf.aspx) can do HTML to PDF - you can try that and see if the problem is resolved. The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) is free for companies with less than 1 million USD in annual revenue.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? (that doesn't involve changing your library!)

Answer (score 3):

Setting the 'CustomWkHtmlArgs' property with the "--dpi 300" option fixed this problem for me, e.g.

```
return new HtmlToPdfConverter
{
    Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait,
    PageHeaderHtml = "<br/>",
    PageFooterHtml = "<div style=\"font-family: Arial;\">Page: <span class=\"page\"></span> of <span class=\"topage\"></span></div>",
    CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--dpi 300",
};
```

This is very vaguely explained on the [NReco PDF website](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx), but without it actually explaining how to set the property.